# how to automatically shutdown BLE scanning after sometime say 10secs

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

my code is as follows

```
scanLeDevice(true);
.......................
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            ViewHolder newUser2 = new ViewHolder("adtv2","vvg2");
            adapter.add(newUser2);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        //invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

I thought that period we are passing would be the limit to scanning, but it does not stop.
Also there are may duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler for this. Use post delayed (afrer 10 seconds) and stop scanning there.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // stop scanning here
           mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
           /*not sure if this is your code to stop scanning but you can use handler for a delay 
           like this.*/
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: I am using it in a similar manner, but it is not stopping. Anything is wrong with my code?

Comment: how to remove the duplicates?is there any simpler method than string comparisions?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

To stop Scanning  `scanLeDevice(false);` use this code.

If it is already in scanning state, for stooping use below code

```
 if (mScanning) {
       mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
       mScanning = false;
     }
```

And set data to adapter in `mLeScanCallback`